# Unable to run 2x Powershell scripts after deploying ARM template via Ansible

Tags: powershell, azure, ansible, azure-resource-manager

I'm deploying an Azure ARM template via Ansible playbook which seems to work fine, however I wish to add the ability to run 2x Powershell scripts after the machine has been deployed. I already have a custom script extension running when the machine is deployed via the ARM template, but I also wish to run 2 more Powershell scripts afterwards.

My Playbook:

```
---
- name: Deploy Azure ARM template.
  hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  gather_facts: false

  vars_files:
   - ./vars/vault.yml
   - ./vars/vars.yml

  tasks:
    - include_vars: vault.yml
    - name: Create Azure Deploy
      azure_rm_deployment:
        client_id: "{{ client_id }}"
        secret: "{{ secret }}"
        subscription_id: "{{ subscription_id }}"
        tenant: "{{ tenant }}"
        state: present
        resource_group_name: AnsibleTest1
        location: UK South
        template: "{{ lookup('file', 'WindowsVirtualMachine.json') }}"
        parameters: "{{ (lookup('file', 'WindowsVirtualMachine.parameters.json') | from_json).parameters }}"

    - name: Run powershell script
      script: files/helloworld1.ps1

    - name: Run powershell script
      script: files/helloworld2.ps1
```

And the error *after* successfully deploying the template:

```
TASK [Run powershell script] ***************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
task path: /home/beefcake/.ansible/azure-json-deploy.yml:25
<127.0.0.1> ESTABLISH LOCAL CONNECTION FOR USER: beefcake
<127.0.0.1> EXEC /bin/sh -c 'echo ~ && sleep 0'
<127.0.0.1> EXEC /bin/sh -c '( umask 77 && mkdir -p "` echo /home/beefcake/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1507219682.48-53342098196230 `" && echo ansible-tmp-1507219682.48-53342098196230="` echo /home/beefcake/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1507219682.48-53342098196230 `" ) && sleep 0'
<127.0.0.1> PUT /home/beefcake/.ansible/files/helloworld1.ps1 TO /home/beefcake/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1507219682.48-53342098196230/helloworld1.ps1
<127.0.0.1> EXEC /bin/sh -c 'chmod u+x /home/beefcake/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1507219682.48-53342098196230/ /home/beefcake/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1507219682.48-53342098196230/helloworld1.ps1 && sleep 0'
<127.0.0.1> EXEC /bin/sh -c ' /home/beefcake/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1507219682.48-53342098196230/helloworld1.ps1  && sleep 0'
<127.0.0.1> EXEC /bin/sh -c 'rm -f -r /home/beefcake/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1507219682.48-53342098196230/ > /dev/null 2>&1 && sleep 0'
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {
    "changed": true, 
    "failed": true, 
    "msg": "non-zero return code", 
    "rc": 127, 
    "stderr": "/home/beefcake/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1507219682.48-53342098196230/helloworld1.ps1: 1: /home/beefcake/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1507219682.48-53342098196230/helloworld1.ps1: =: not found\n/home/beefcake/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1507219682.48-53342098196230/helloworld1.ps1: 2: /home/beefcake/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1507219682.48-53342098196230/helloworld1.ps1: Set-Content: not found\n", 
    "stdout": "", 
    "stdout_lines": []
}
    to retry, use: --limit @/home/beefcake/.ansible/azure-json-deploy.retry

PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=2    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=1
```

As far as I can tell, the playbook *script* option should send the script to the machine and run it locally, but for some reason it cannot find the script I have in a subfolder of the playbook.

Folder structure:

```
.ansible (folder)
  - ansible.cfg
  - azure-json-deploy.yml
  - azure_rm.ini
  - azure_rm.py
  - WindowsVirtualMachine.json
  - WindowsVirtualMachine.parameters.json
  - vars (folder)
     - vars.yml
     - vault.yml
  - files (folder)
     - helloworld1.ps1
     - helloworld2.ps1
```

Am I missing something?

edit
This is the 2nd playbook I've created which **4c74356b41** advised me to do.

```
---
# This playbook tests the script module on Windows hosts
- name: Run powershell script 1
  hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:
    - name: Run powershell script
      script: files/helloworld1.ps1
# This playbook tests the script module on Windows hosts
- name: Run powershell script 2
  hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:
    - name: Run powershell script
      script: files/helloworld2.ps1
```

Which still generates the same error:

```
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {
    "changed": true, 
    "failed": true, 
    "msg": "non-zero return code", 
    "rc": 127, 
    "stderr": "/home/beefcake/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1507288326.16-187870805725578/helloworld1.ps1: 1: /home/beefcake/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1507288326.16-187870805725578/helloworld1.ps1: =: not found\n/home/beefcake/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1507288326.16-187870805725578/helloworld1.ps1: 2: /home/beefcake/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1507288326.16-187870805725578/helloworld1.ps1: Set-Content: not found\n", 
    "stdout": "", 
    "stdout_lines": []
}
    to retry, use: --limit @/home/beefcake/.ansible/azure-json-deploy.retry
```

Comment: Before you'd be able to use Ansible, you need to enable WinRM on the Windows machine, modify connection profile on the network interface, possibly configure FW (both Windows and Azure), and optionally configure SSL certificates. Judging from your post and edits, you probably don't do it in your template, you're probably not even aware of that. As for running PowerShell scripts - I would suggest modifying the template to use DSC extension instead of Ansible (you'd need to do it anyway to prepare the instance for WinRM connections) - there are examples on GitHub Azure quickstart templates.

Answer (score 0):

What ansible is trying to do is copy the file from localhost to localhost. Because the play is scoped to localhost.

I would imagine you dont have that host in the hosts file when you launch the playbook.
You need to add the host to ansible and scope script tasks to that host.

You can either create another playbook to do that or add a add_host step in the current one.

```
- add_host:
    name: name
```

To scope tasks to the new hosts I'm using import_playbook directive, which imports another playbook that is scoped to the host(s) in question. There might be a better way.

Comment: I've looked at the Ansible documentation on their website, and a few examples online. From what I can tell all I need to do is place `- import_playbook: imported.yml` at the bottom of my play, but I am prompted with an error: **META: ran handlers. META: ran handlers ERROR! the field 'hosts' is required but was not set** So I placed `hosts: localhost` underneath import_playbook, but that also brings up an error: **ERROR! 'hosts' is not a valid attribute for a PlaybookInclude**. Can you please give me an example as to where to put the import_playbook?

Comment: you need to create a separate playbook that would do what you want to do (run 2 scripts). it should look like the one you have, so have name, hosts, tasks, etc.

Comment: I've amended my 2nd playbook as advised (see above), but it still points to a temp location...

Comment: the `hosts` directive should point to the host you are configuring, not localhost and probably `connection` shouldn't be set to `local`